# Printing a data frame in Pandas and Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and trying to solve a problem of a basic code to form a data frame. I wrote two rows the data frame to try, but it is not working. I do not know the problem is about the continuation of the dictionaries and the list on the new line or something else. Do I need to use backslash when moving to the new line? Any help is appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'#':1, 'Name': 'BS', 'Type 1': 'grass', 'type 2': 'poison', 'Total': 318, 'HP': 45, 'Attack': 49, 'Defense': 49, 'Sp. Atk': 65, 'Sp. Def': 65, 'Speed': 45, 'Generation': 1, 'Legendary':'false'}, {'#':2, 'Name': 'IS', 'Type 1': 'grass', 'type 2': 'poison', 'Total': 405, 'HP': 60, 'Attack': 62, Defense': 63, 'Sp. Atk': 80, 'Sp. Def': 80, 'Speed': 60, 'Generation': 1, 'Legendary':'false'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Defense': 63  this is missing apostrophe add that try to print it will work

Comment: `Defense` is missing a starting quote

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is syntax error with the ‘defense’ key element. There is a missing apostrophe.

```
data = [{'#':1, 'Name': 'BS', 'Type 1': 'grass', 'type 2': 'poison', 'Total': 318, 'HP': 45, 'Attack': 49, 
         'Defense': 49, 'Sp. Atk': 65, 'Sp. Def': 65, 'Speed': 45, 'Generation': 1, 'Legendary':'false'},
        {'#':2, 'Name': 'IS', 'Type 1': 'grass', 'type 2': 'poison', 'Total': 405, 'HP': 60, 'Attack': 62, 
         'Defense': 63, 'Sp. Atk': 80, 'Sp. Def': 80, 'Speed': 60, 'Generation': 1, 'Legendary':'false'}]
>>> pd.DataFrame(data)


#   Name    Type 1  type 2  Total   HP  Attack  Defense Sp. Atk Sp. Def Speed   Generation  Legendary
0   1   BS  grass   poison  318 45  49  49  65  65  45  1   false
1   2   IS  grass   poison  405 60  62  63  80  80  60  1   false
```

Comment: Correct.  Also, at the risk of stating the obvious, to get the dataframe to render, you need to add a line: df

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'#':1, 'Name': 'BS', 'Type 1': 'grass', 'type 2': 'poison', 'Total': 318, 
         'HP': 45, 'Attack': 49, 'Defense': 49, 'Sp. Atk': 65, 'Sp. Def': 65, 'Speed': 45,
         'Generation': 1, 'Legendary':'false'}, {'#':2, 'Name': 'IS', 'Type 1': 'grass', 
                                                 'type 2': 'poison', 'Total': 405, 'HP': 60,
                                                 'Attack': 62, 'Defense': 63, 
                                                 'Sp. Atk': 80, 'Sp. Def': 80, 
                                                 'Speed': 60, 'Generation': 1, 'Legendary':'false'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

[image: here is the output]